# Destroy progressbar from progressbar.js

Tags: javascript

I have multiple progress bars from progressbar.js and I want to destroy all of them. All progress bars names are after string from the list. for example, connected users are: User1, User2, John. Then progress bars are going to be named: progressBarUser1, progressBarUser2, progressBarJohn.

```
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       console.log('Connection Lost');
       socket.disconnect();

       usersList.forEach(function(v) {
         window["progressBar" + v.userID] = null; //Doesn't work
       });
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the different progress bars in a variable. Make sure the variable is available both when declaring the progress bars and when you want to remove them. Then use the [.destroy()](https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/#destroy) function on each one.

Code example:

HTML:

```
<div id="line"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="semicircle"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var progressBars = [];

function addAnimations() {
    progressBars.push(new ProgressBar.Line('#line'));
    progressBars.push(new ProgressBar.Circle('#circle'));
    progressBars.push(new ProgressBar.SemiCircle('#semicircle'));

    progressBars.forEach(function(bar){
       bar.animate(1.0);
    });
}

function destroyAll() {
    progressBars.forEach(function(bar){
       bar.destroy();
    });
}

addAnimations();
destroyAll();
```